# Display elements vertically centered in a div

Tags: html, css

I have this very simple HTML and CSS ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JS8AN/)) and I just want the input and the links to be displayed all aligned vertically in the middle of the div, something like this:

---

```
                             -----------     -----------     -----------
      ------------------     |         |     |         |     |         |
      |                |     |         |     |         |     |         |
      ------------------     |         |     |         |     |         |
                             -----------     -----------     -----------
```

---

I know I can use `display: table` and `vertical-align: middle`, but that doesn't work for me as I explain in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942633/display-elements-vertically-centered-in-a-div/19942974#comment29713320_19942974) below... is there any other approach I can use?

```
<div>
    <input type="text"/>
    <a></a>    
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
</div>

-------------------------------

div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

input {
    display: inline-block;
}

a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Centering stuff vertically can be a real pain. I usually use the technique you said you did not want to use. There are really very few options using only CSS.

Comment: Or you can use the negative margin technique: #content {position:absolute; top:50%; height:240px; margin-top:-120px; /* negative half of the height */}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all the elements are `inline` and `inline-block`, you can simply use `line-height` and `vertical-align` like so:

**CSS:**

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;

    /* Match the DIV height and get rid of the font size which throws off alignment */
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 0;
}

input {
    display: inline-block;

    /* Vertically align the input and restore its font size */
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 16px;
}

a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: white;

    /* Match the element height to center the text */
    line-height: 80px;

    /* Vertically align the anchor and restore its font size */
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SombreErmine/2g89V/2/)

Tested in IE7, IE10, Chrome, Firefox.

Comment: 1+ This is a better solution, though it won't work for dynamic heights... if the OP wants a solution for this he should just use the `display:table-cell` approach.. don't know why he is opposed to it, as it's perfectly fine.. it's not like the tabular layouts, and it's not hackish.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this before, but I was missing the `font-size: 0`... that trick is brilliant!

Comment: @JoshC, I didn't include this is the question to make it shorter, but I'll exaplin it to you: I don't want to use `display: table` because after that "red line" in my example, I do want to display something as a table. So, if I set in the red line 4 cells 25% each (1 for the input and 3 for the links), then when I add another row to the table to display the data I do want to display as a table I'm not able to display, let's say 5 cells 20% each, because the cells in the 2nd row take the same width that those in 1st... Moreover when I try to add a box-shadow to the `table-row` it doesn't work.

Comment: @MikO Ah, makes sense now. You weren't opposed to it - it just didn't work.. glad you found a solution though!

Comment: @JoshC, you're right, it seemed that I didn't want to use that approach just because I didn't like it :) I added a link to the comment with the explanation above...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will need more element. I like to center my elements using a combination of css positon and margin.

I wrapped all element in a div.container:

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and each in a div.item:

```
.item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

then added a class on those elements (input and a)

```
.vertical-align {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

A example could be seen in http://jsfiddle.net/VEQe2/